# Add text file and images to build in the Jar - Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I'm really facing too much of problem when building the Jar. The problem is within Netbeans it's work fine but if I try to run the .jar file from the /dest folder, it's not calling the additional text files and images. I tried various solutions but cannot really solve it. This is the directory that I stored the .java files. `src/RX/example.java` where RX is the package name. I inserted all the images and text files inside the same directory and called like this.

```
JButton btnStart = new JButton(new ImageIcon("src/RX/start1.png")); //Set Image for Button
```

Now reading from text file:

```
Reader reader = null; 
JTextArea jtaUser= new JTextArea(); 
try {
    reader = new FileReader(new File("src/RX/rxUser.txt"));
    jtaUser.read(reader, "");
} catch (Exception exp) {
} finally {
    try {
        reader.close();
    } catch (Exception exp) {
    }
}
```

As i said earlier, the problem is if I run from Netbeans everything's worked fine but the text files and images not included in the .jar file. Thus, when I open the .jar, the button seems empty and when reading the file it freezes.

I need an answer for the same coding I did above here. So, please tell me or show me how I can set the image and read the text file rather than giving links to other answers. I would really appreciate your answers for this question. Thank you.

Comment: Any files that the .jar depends upon need to be moved alongside the .jar. This is essentially what an installer does; it places the files in the correct directories relative to the executable.

Comment: Read them as resources, not as files.

Comment: @DaveNewton How to read as resources? Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read a file as a `File` object, the program will try and read from the local file system. If you are going to use a file as a resource, then you should read them as such.

You can get in `InputStream` from `getClass().GetResourceAsStream()` and then pass that `InputStream` to an `InputStreamReader` to use for the `read()` method. So in your case, you would use

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/RX/rxUsers.txt");
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is);
textArea.read(reader, ..);
```

The path I used is determined by the classpath. Since `RX` dir is a direct child of `src`, it will be in the root of the class path. To get to the root of the class path from the calling class (using getClass()), you need the extra `/` in the front of your path.

To read image, you can either use `getResourceAsStream()` which returns an `InputStream`, or use `getResource()` which return an URL. You can pass the URL to an `ImageIcon(URL)` or an `ImageIO.read(URL)` which return an `Image` object. Pick which one, based on your needs. Example:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("/RX/start1.png"); // you will need to 
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);                // handle exception
```

Comment: Thanks. How about the image?

Comment: Just updated at the bottom. You can pass the URL to an `ImageIcon(URL)` or an `ImageIO.read(URL)` which return an `Image`

Comment: Note that when you just pass a string to `ImageIcon` is will search in the file system. So you can either pass the URL to it or an `Image` obtained from `ImageIO.read()`

Comment: Thank you. it's worked. But, i'm confused when trying the same for FileWriter. Hope you can help me with this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979791/change-filewriter-to-outputstreamwriter

Comment: jar doesn't allow writing into. Normally if you need to write to something like a properties or something, your program should create a file on the local file system that it writes to

Comment: So what do you want me to do? Magically make writing to a jar possible? I told you what to do. Have your application create a directory and file specifically for your application, somewhere on the local file system, when the application is first launched. The `user.home` is a common directory.

Comment: Look at it this way. When you installed netbeans, the installation created some files needed for the application in the install directory of your file system. When you run netbeans, it reads from that directory. When you change properties and settings, they are written to some file in the directory. That's the same thing you need to do, if your application it to be distibuted, and you want read and write