# Change FileWriter to OutputStreamWriter?

Tags: java, outputstream, filewriter, bufferedwriter, stringreader

How do I convert the `FileWriter` to `OutputStreamWriter`? This is the directory that I stored the .java files. `src/RX/example.java` where RX is the package name. I inserted all the images and text files inside the same directory. Here is my working code with FileWriter.

```
try {
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader("Save this Message");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(stringReader);

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("src/RX/rxUser.txt");
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

    for(String line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line != null; line =bufferedReader.readLine()) {               
        bufferedWriter.write(line);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();                   
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
    bufferedWriter.close();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

I actually can go on with this code but in order to work with .jar I have to use the .txt file as a resource. Can someone please alter my code. I am using Netbeans. Thank you.

Comment: *"... in order to work with .jar I have to use the .txt file as a resource"*.  Please say exactly what you mean by this.  Are you trying to update a resource file in a JAR file?  If not, it is really difficult ... and almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: yes, i'm just trying to update a resource file in a JAR file. Please help me how I can actually do that.

Comment: Why do you think that OutputStreamWriter will be better for you usage than FileWriter ? Where do you want to write to ?

Comment: I didn't looked at previous comment. If you **really** want to write to a jar, remember that a jar is simply a zip file. But unless if you have an **very imperious** reason to do so, allways use a java compiler to update a jar.